# Display loading message until fully parsing json iOS

Tags: ios, json, parsing, loading

Ok here's the question, how do I simulate loading message until I fully downloaded the data from the server. I have this problem as I can't pass the data to the next view controller when  the properties to hold the data from the downloaded json is still nil. So, How can I simulate a loading message until I fully parsed the Json.

Here's my code to fetch data

```
-(void)fetchFeed
{
NSString *requestString = @"some website";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSDictionary * jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
    self.locations = jsonObject[@"someKey"];
    NSLog(@"%@", self.locations);
}


];

[dataTask resume];
}




- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
[self.view addSubview:hud];
[hud show:YES];
[hud setLabelText:@"Loading..."];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
    [self fetchFeed];   //Network activity
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        //do stuff after json download
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

Comment: Use **MBProgressHUD**.  note that **parsing** takes no time, microseconds.  the openly time involved is network connection time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please check out my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23843752/alert-view-not-functioning/23844137#23844137).. It pretty much does the same thing that you are looking for..

I have used MBProgressHUD to show the loading message.

Its as simple as

```
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
        [self.view addSubview:hud];
        [hud show:YES];
        [hud setLabelText:@"Loading..."];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{
        //Network activity
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //do stuff after json download
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });
    });
```

for a more detailed answer check the link.

*************EDIT*******************
As you are using `NSURLSession` it allows you to perform background download operations. As per the code you posted, we don't to start a new thread using `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{})`

Please try this..

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self fetchFeed];   //Network activity
}


-(void)fetchFeed
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:hud];
    [hud show:YES];
    [hud setLabelText:@"Loading..."];

    NSString *requestString = @"some website";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
    NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [[self.session dataTaskWithRequest:req completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        NSDictionary * jsonObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        self.locations = jsonObject[@"someKey"];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.locations);
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
         });
    }] resume];

}
```

This should work.

Comment: But the loading ends before i finish downloading the data.

Comment: I can tell from NSLog. cuz NSLog should display something but loading pages finishes before NSLog could print anything out.

Comment: i need to see your download code. The way you have implemented it

Comment: I have edited my answer.. Sorry for the delay .. i was caught with something else.

Comment: Omg You're a life saver. I'm actually in a hackathon right now. Is the problem due to threading stuff.